# How to remove default CSS from TextField in flex?

Tags: css, apache-flex, textfield, htmltext

I'm in serious fight with it. I need to set the defaultTextFormat of a TextField component to my own values. I can't do that since the component does not use the defaultTextFormat if it has it is already using the format from CSS stylesheet as said here http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#defaultTextFormat :

> **Note:** You can't set this property if a style sheet is applied to the text field.

My question is: is there a way to remove the CSS propertis of the text field? How could I "override" this style sheet ??

I want be able to do that without overwrite the CSS file or write my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you give your own CSS properties to a component, the default properties will automatically get overridden.

Thanks

Comment: Actually flex throws an exception when I do that. It says that I cannot assign a style to a component that already has a style.